# How to customise GMSAutocompleteViewController for iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicolor, gmsautocomplete

I am using Google autocomplete placekicker in ios. It shows me controller with native design. I want to customise it's navigation bar colour.But I am not able to do it.
Below is the code

```
        let autocompleteController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
        autocompleteController.tintColor = UIColor.red
        autocompleteController.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = Constant.AppColor.navigationColor
        autocompleteController.delegate = self
        self.present(autocompleteController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

I have written this code for adapting light/dark mode:

**Swift**

```
let controller:GMSAutocompleteViewController! = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
   if UIScreen.mainScreen.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == UIUserInterfaceStyleDark  {
      controller.primaryTextColor = UIColor.whiteColor
      controller.secondaryTextColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor
      controller.tableCellSeparatorColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor
      controller.tableCellBackgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor
   } else {
      controller.primaryTextColor = UIColor.blackColor
      controller.secondaryTextColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor
      controller.tableCellSeparatorColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor
      controller.tableCellBackgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor
   }
}
```

**Objective-C**

```
GMSAutocompleteViewController *controller = [[GMSAutocompleteViewController alloc] init];
if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
   if(UIScreen.mainScreen.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == UIUserInterfaceStyleDark ){
      controller.primaryTextColor = UIColor.whiteColor;
      controller.secondaryTextColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor;
      controller.tableCellSeparatorColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor;
      controller.tableCellBackgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor;
   } else {
      controller.primaryTextColor = UIColor.blackColor;
      controller.secondaryTextColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor;
      controller.tableCellSeparatorColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor;
      controller.tableCellBackgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor;
   }
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[Google Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete) document can help you.

According to document, use [UIAppearanceProtocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/index.html) to customise visual theme.

Look at section "**Customize text and background colors**" in this document.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I was able to customise some elements in Swift like so :

```
     // Sets the background of results - top line
    autocompleteController.primaryTextColor = UIColor.black

    // Sets the background of results - second line
    autocompleteController.secondaryTextColor = Color.black

   // Sets the text color of the text in search field
    UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).defaultTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor.rawValue: UIColor.white]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Please use the below code to support light and dark mode in iOS.

let autocompleteController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
autocompleteController.delegate = self

if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            if UIScreen.main.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .dark  {
                autocompleteController.primaryTextColor = UIColor.white
                autocompleteController.secondaryTextColor = UIColor.lightGray
                autocompleteController.tableCellSeparatorColor = UIColor.lightGray
                autocompleteController.tableCellBackgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
            } else {
                autocompleteController.primaryTextColor = UIColor.black
                autocompleteController.secondaryTextColor = UIColor.lightGray
                autocompleteController.tableCellSeparatorColor = UIColor.lightGray
                autocompleteController.tableCellBackgroundColor = UIColor.white
            }
        }

To access the full code, please check out the below link.
https://gist.github.com/imnaveensharma/fb41063c1f858da15199ee7545f51422
```

Answer (score 0):

Better solution for iOS > 13 for Light and Dark Mode not to do:

```
autocompleteController.primaryTextColor = UIColor.label
autocompleteController.secondaryTextColor = UIColor.secondaryLabel
autocompleteController.tableCellSeparatorColor = UIColor.separator
autocompleteController.tableCellBackgroundColor = UIColor.systemBackground
```

Answer (score 0):

Update code for Swift 5+

full code will look like this.

```
// Present the Autocomplete view controller 
    @objc func autoCompleteClicked() {
        
        let autocompleteController:GMSAutocompleteViewController! = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            if UIScreen.main.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .dark  {
                autocompleteController.primaryTextColor = UIColor.white
                autocompleteController.secondaryTextColor = UIColor.lightGray
                autocompleteController.tableCellSeparatorColor = UIColor.lightGray
                autocompleteController.tableCellBackgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
           } else {
            autocompleteController.primaryTextColor = UIColor.black
            autocompleteController.secondaryTextColor = UIColor.lightGray
            autocompleteController.tableCellSeparatorColor = UIColor.lightGray
            autocompleteController.tableCellBackgroundColor = UIColor.white
           }
        }
        
        
        
     // let autocompleteController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
      autocompleteController.delegate = self

      // Specify the place data types to return.
      let fields: GMSPlaceField = GMSPlaceField(rawValue:UInt(GMSPlaceField.all.rawValue))
  
        
        
      autocompleteController.placeFields = fields

      // Specify a filter.
      let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
      filter.type = .address
      autocompleteController.autocompleteFilter = filter

      // Display the autocomplete view controller.
      present(autocompleteController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

I updated the code of @Sabrina